# pip install pyqtchart hangs before giving _in_process.py: '/usr/bin/qmake -recursive PyQtChart.pro' failed returning 3

Tags: pip, pyqt5, qmake, python-3.9, pyqtchart

I have been trying to install PyQtChart in a Python 3.9 pipenv to use in conjunction with PyQt5==5.15.6 (as this is the latest PyQtChart version), but whenever I run `pip install pyqtchart` or `pip install pyqtchart==5.15.6` the process nearly completes, reaching `Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ...` before failing with the following error:

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      pyproject.toml: line 7: using '[tool.sip.metadata]' to specify the project metadata is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0, use '[project]' instead
      Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
      These bindings will be built: QtChart.
      Generating the QtChart bindings...
      /home/name/.local/share/virtualenvs/webapp-0jMMjEx8/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/bindings/QtCore/QtCoremod.sip: line 66: '%Plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0
      /home/name/.local/share/virtualenvs/webapp-0jMMjEx8/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/bindings/QtCore/qbytearray.sip: line 118: '%BIGetReadBufferCode' is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0
      /home/name/.local/share/virtualenvs/webapp-0jMMjEx8/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/bindings/QtCore/qbytearray.sip: line 131: '%BIGetSegCountCode' is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0
      /home/name/.local/share/virtualenvs/webapp-0jMMjEx8/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/bindings/QtCore/qbytearray.sip: line 138: '%BIGetCharBufferCode' is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0
      Generating the .pro file for the QtChart module...
      Generating the top-level .pro file...
      Generating the Makefiles...
      _in_process.py: '/usr/bin/qmake -recursive PyQtChart.pro' failed returning 3
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.`
```

I have tried other versions of both PyQt5 and PyQtChart, I have cleared my pip and pipenv caches, and I have upgraded pip to the latest version. Only additional context I can think of is that I'm using Raspberry Pi OS Lite on a Pi 4. Hopefully someone sees the error of my ways?